# When click on link load in PHP page in DIV. Pass info to PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to load a php page on clicking a link, so:

```
<a href="" onclick="loadPage('page.php'); return false">
    Create Character
</a>
<br/>;
```

where loadPage is a function that loads a php page in the current page's div. How do you pass information to page.php without using a querystring? For example setting a session etc.

Comment: You use a querystring, why on earth would you mess with sessions or cookies when passing information with a GET request is so simple ?

Comment: I think you're looking for ajax with something like jQuery. That will load another page's contents into a div.

Comment: adeno, i figured using a session and hiding information is better implementation. With querystring, users can go to a page by entering it into the browser and i want to prevent that.

Comment: @user2361103 no its not like that when you use .post in jquery trust me. and lets think about the session way so if you want a session to be set you should do a server request using ajax or the compelete request, using get or post.(-:. the best way I think is the way I suggested in my answer. so please check it.(-:

Comment: @imsiso - the click handler returns false, so you could use "uranus" as a href, it still would'nt redirect anywhere!

Comment: I'm pretty darn sure that return false in the onclick handler works in all browsers, and prevents the anchor from redirecting.

Comment: @adeneo ok I give up (-:.and 2+ like to you.

Comment: @imsiso - You are partially right, an empty href will reload the page, while a hash will just scroll to the top, but javascript prevents this. I'd still use the hash to make sure the page does'nt reload for users with javascript disabled, but that would'nt run the function either, so nothing would really happen.

Comment: I always use '#' for as you said javascript off times. so you mean that `return false;` can easily prevent that?